# Calendar Shape (Triangle inside div with border-radius)

Tags: css, css-shapes

I've been struggling to realise this CSS shape:

[image: goal]

I've been using CSS transforms and pseudo-elements to achieve my goal and I got a decent result but it's not perfect. The corners need to be less sharp.
It's also worth pointing out that the cut-off triangle part needs to be transparent.

Here is what I came up with:
https://jsfiddle.net/e1xzjghL/11/

HTML

```
<div class="date">
    <div class="date__month">April</div>
    <div class="date__day">20</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.date {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(top left, rgba(255,255,255,0.3), transparent);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), transparent);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: .4rem;
  min-width: 37px;

  //centering
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

  &__day {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }

  &::before, &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 18.5px solid black;
    bottom: -18.5px;
    transform: rotate(.25turn) scaleX(.2);
    z-index: -1;
  }
  &::before {
    left: 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
  }
  &::after {
    right: 0;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

J

Comment: I would use a background image with the transparent triangle at the bottom of the image to achieve the desired effect and look.

Comment: Can you not just add a border radius to the after, before elements?

Comment: @Beth I'd rather not use an image if possible, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JamieButtonsCoulter, no it's not rendering well because the triangle part is already built with the border trick.

Comment: @jor1s Seems to look ok for me? https://jsfiddle.net/e1xzjghL/14/

Comment: @JamieButtonsCoulter Well done ! I guess I've set the border-radius on the wrong corners ... probably because of the rotation. I'm wondering which solution should I go now, with yours I do not need an extra div for my transparent radial background..
Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `transform:skew()` for the lower part instead of border trick and apply some `border-radius`

```css
body {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  height: 100vh;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.date {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background: black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), transparent);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(top left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), transparent);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-width: 37px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 52px;
}

.date__day {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.date::before,
.date::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  background: #0e0e0e;
  left: 0;
  top: 48px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.date::after {
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="date">
  <div class="date__month">April</div>
  <div class="date__day">20</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer ! The corners look much better this way. I'm fiddling with your answer but beside the `z-index: -1` on pseudo-elements they don't seem to go behind the main element. Is it related to the fact that skew transforms mess with the z-axis?

The `::after` element is also overflowing the main div in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: (I've fixed the overflowing element by setting the main element width to a number divisible by 2, I guess it was some rounding problems).

Comment: @jor1s actually `z-index:-1` on pseudo elements place them behind the content of the div thats how it works...and for the overflow part yes you are right its the main element width because I have used `50%` in the pseudo element width...

Comment: yes I just realised I was being dumb about the z-index, the background  is meant to be in the background. It's a problem as I need to have a white transparent radial gradient over the main black background.

Comment: I've added an extra div for the radial gradient. I'd rather not but I can't find another way with the skew approach.
I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jor1s just try to change the top value of `:before` and `:after`. Answer is updated with gradient background...

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot, I feel like this is cleaner than the border trick. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a lot of code for `transform:skew()` and pseudo elements, you could simply use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to create your shape.

```css
.date {
  border-radius: .3rem;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, #777, #000);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: .5rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 52px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0,0 100%,6% 100%,50% 92%,94% 100%,100% 100%,100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,0 100%,6% 100%,50% 92%,94% 100%,100% 100%,100% 0);
}

.date__day {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="date">
  <div class="date__month">Mars</div>
  <div class="date__day">27</div>
</div>
```

([browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path))